# Is $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(0,n]\subset\mathbb R$ open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(0,n]\subset\mathbb R$.

We know that $\mathbb R$ is both open and closed. Hence, by looking at the complement $A^{\complement}$ defined as $(-\infty,0]$ we say it is closed. Thus, $A$ is open.

Is my thinking correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, or you can think directly, $A=(0,\infty)$ is a ray. Every ray in $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: Or you can show that $\bigcup (0,n]=\bigcup (0,n)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I was struggling with this transition, i.e. $]\to)$. How would I show this?

Comment: Using an intermediate form: $\bigcup(0,n]=\bigcup(0,n+1)$. (which is also enough on its own.)

Comment: Thank you. I think I get the concept.